# How to change Tor browser time zone

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, time

Is there a way to change the time zone displayed by the Tor browser? I seen that, it is set +0 UTC for everyone.

Comment: Any change in time zone will act as a fingerprint and may identify you as one of a kind TBB users.

Comment: Yes Roya I know, thank you for your response, but still my issue isn't fixed ;)

Answer (score -1):

In `about:config` set `privacy.use_utc_timezone` to `false` it will use your computer's time zone.

Comment: Allowing Tor Browser to use a local timezone will result in you being fingerprintable and geographically fingerprintable and will break your anonymity. Do not follow these steps because this user has no idea what they're doing.

Comment: This is not working